# Convergence Warning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations

Tags: scikit-learn

trying to run the following code:

```
# Setup the pipeline steps: steps
steps = [('imputation', SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')),
         ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
         ('elasticnet', ElasticNet())]


# Create the pipeline: pipeline 
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)

# Specify the hyperparameter space
parameters = {'elasticnet__l1_ratio':np.linspace(0,1,30)}

# Create train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=42)

# Create the GridSearchCV object: gm_cv
gm_cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters)

# Fit to the training set
gm_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Compute and print the metrics
r2 = gm_cv.score(X_test, y_test)
print("Tuned ElasticNet Alpha: {}".format(gm_cv.best_params_))
print("Tuned ElasticNet R squared: {}".format(r2))
```

is giving the following warning message:

```
ConvergenceWarning: Objective did not converge. You might want to increase the number of iterations
```

Comment: Perhaps increase `ElasticNet`'s `max_iter` beyond the default value?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Isn't the message clear enough?

Comment: It is clear now. I recognized  I have to increase the number of iterations but I did not know how. Now I know.

Comment: How can you increase the number of iterations?